# Why android studio not showing project files

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I've been working on this problem for about 2 days. I've tried different things but it's not working.
[Please take  a look](https://r2.easyimg.io/28hi3lv2f/ads%C4%B1z.png)

What I have done so far

1. Reinstall everything (including windows)
2. deleting .idea file invalidate and restart
3. restore ide settings

Comment: try delete .idea AND xxx.iml